# Filtering search results directly in the scrollview

Tags: java, android, scrollview, searchview, android-imagebutton

I am new here. I need to ask something. I am building an android app in android stuido. I implemented 1 of my searchviews in an activity. In that activity, below the searchview is a scrollview with some imagebuttons in it. When I search in the searchview, I want that in the scrollview to be shown only the imagebuttons whose description or id is related to the search. How can I do that? And also I don't want the searchview to show me a list, but I want it to directly filter the results in the scrollview. 
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Implement  TextWatcher  using adapter .

Comment: @ChetanJoshi can you please add an example?

Answer (score 0):

To achive this

first implement a listview or a recyclerview(since you are a begineer, try listview its more simpler and easier) instead of a scrollview
Once you successfully implement a listview look for `Textwatcher` which reads your edittext as you modify it and update the listview with it.
Here's a [demo](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-edittext-with-textwatcher) for help

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem is that for the app that I am building, it is necessary that the search results to be filtered directly in scrollview in the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the scroll view into a recycler view. Earlier I faced the same issue and concluded that we have to use the recycler view to implement the search view.I hope this will help you.